# need solution for puppet script- while executing script we can select which line uncomment and execute

Tags: puppet

I want to execute a puppet script.

The command in puppet command prompt:

```
puppet agent -t --server servername.r7.corp.local --environment adfs -v
```

Before executing script it should ask for uncomment script line which we want to execute then save it and execute it.

Finally after executing uncomment the lines which we commented at the time of execution.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to write: _"After executing uncomment the lines which we commented at the time of execution."_ but not: _"After executing **comment** the lines which we've **uncommented** at the time of execution."_ So the opposite, am I right?

Comment: yes sir , can you please suggest @theDavidBarton

Comment: Sorry I am not that familiar with puppet. Haven't you considered using conditionals instead of commenting out scripts? https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_conditional.html

Comment: @theDavidBarton My linkedin in Alamdar Hussaini , would you mind to connect with me ? alamdar28@gmail.com

Comment: If you're talking about modifying the Puppet manifest files on the master before and after building a catalog for the agent, that is simply not going to happen.  *The master* decides, based on manifests and data stored *there* what each agent's configuration is supposed to be.  But if you want to apply only a subset of those resources then you might want to look into [`--tags`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/man/agent.html).